# how to get all records in a webtable when one column is merged

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to get all the records in google calendar (eg: Meeting and demo)
Since “Meeting” is mentioned in both May 1st  and 2nd ,Issue I am facing while retrieving data from table through selenium webdriver is , it only shows “Meeting” in May 1st but nothing for May 2nd .
Wanna know how to code this in selenium webdriver so to get all data in a particular cell, even when the records are mentioned in the format shown in the screenshot.

[Google calendar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzl48.jpg)

Code i have tried:

```
// All the tables in google calendar
List<WebElement> totalTables = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@id='mvEventContainer']/div"));
int tablecount = totalTables.size();

for (int table=0;table<tablecount;table++){
        int tableIn = table+1;
        String tableXpath = "//*[@id='mvEventContainer']/div["+tableIn+"]/table[2]/tbody";
        WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(tableXpath));
      //To locate rows of a table.
        List<WebElement> rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

        int rows_count = rows_table.size();
for (int row=0; row<rows_count; row++){
    List<WebElement> Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
       //To calculate no of columns(cells) In that specific row.
         int columns_count = Columns_row.size();
        for (int column=0; column<columns_count; column++){
            String celtext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
               if (celtext.toLowerCase().contains(Meeting.toLowerCase()))
               System.out.println("Cell Value Of row number "+row+" and column number "+column+" Is "+celtext);
```

Issue is 
Output given is "Cell Value Of row number 1 and column number 1 Meeting"

which is value present in May 1st but same "Meeting" is present in May 2nd also which is not given as a output since the column is merged and Meeting is mentioned only once as shown in screenshot.

Comment: can you add the code what did you try

Comment: I have updated the description with the code i have tried and that isnt giving me the expected output. It returns value only for one cell (May 1st and not for the other cell (may 2nd) since both are merged, where as i want it to return "Meeting" as twice (both for may 1st and 2nd)  (refer screenshot for google calendar example i have taken)